# How to Start the MySQL Windows Service without administrative rights on Windows?

Tags: c#, mysql, windows, winforms, windows-services

I'm currently making a program in WinForms with C# that uses an internal MySQL database, and I want the service to start and stop when the program starts and stops. The database is installed on the computer and not on an external server, and I want to ensure that it always starts so it doesn't have any error, as I have had some trouble with the MySQL service shutting down itself.
The problem is that as it is a program that can be installed on any computer, if the user doesn't have administrative rights, it will throw an error saying "access denied" when trying to start the MySQL Windows service.

So the question is, is there any way I can start the MySQL service without administrative rights from C# code?

I also thought of starting the mysqld.exe file as it doesn't throw any error, but it doesn't keep active after it's started.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are embedding a database with an application (rather than running it on a server) MySQL is almost certainly the wrong choice. Look into using SQLite or another embedded database

Comment: @NickBailey why is it a bad choice?

Comment: A few reasons. One is what you are experiencing, MySQL needs to be run as a separate process and service, with all the management overhead that implies. Sqlite runs in your application, so there's no separate process.

Comment: Thanks @NickBailey, I'm still learning about all of this, and I really appreciate your comment.

Comment: Starting/Stopping/Installing/Uninstalling a Windows Service sadly requires Admin Rights (or other non-default explicit rights).  Full stop. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/grant-users-rights-manage-services